# applying a query as a filter on another query's result MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries as below,

```
A SELECT DISTINCT meta_value, meta_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`='destination';
B SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish';
```

What I want is something like this,

```
SELECT meta_value FROM A WHERE A.meta_id = B.ID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  A.meta_value, A.meta_id 
FROM `wp_postmeta` A
INNER JOIN wp_posts  B
ON meta_id = id
WHERE A.`meta_key`= 'destination'
AND B.post_status = 'publish' 
GROUP BY   A.meta_value
```

Comment: says MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec ) but published posts have destinations.. its not returning it.

Comment: It worked after I made these changes, < WHERE A.`meta_key`=B.'destination' > should be just < WHERE A.`meta_key`='destination' > because 'destination' is a value. and I was matching wrong id's, I meant post_id ie., < ON post_id = id > my bad. Thanks a lot Samir.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  meta_value
FROM `wp_postmeta` wpm,
  wp_posts wp
WHERE wp.ID = wpm.meta_id
    AND wpm.`meta_key` = 'destination'
    AND wp.post_status = 'publish';
```